# Django Get Root Path From Current URL

Tags: python, html, django, django-templates, wagtail

I am developing a Django website using the Wagtail CMS. I have a navbar at the top of the page where using template tags, it loops through pages in the `navigation` variable.

```
{% for item in navigation.menu_items.all %}
    <a class="nav-link {% if request.get_full_path == item.link %}active{% endif %}" href="{{ item.link }}" {% if item.open_in_new_tab %} target="_blank"{% endif %}>{{ item.title }}</a>
{% endfor %}
```

Say that the URL is `http://localhost:8000/blog/` and the page URL is the same, then the `active` class is applied to that iteration.

The problem arises when I am on a page with the URL such as `http://localhost:8000/blog/example-blog-post/`, this does not match with `http://localhost:8000/blog/` and the active class is not applied, even though I am in the blog.

Is there a way to strip the URL and only keeping the root path, so `http://localhost:8000/blog/example-blog-post/` becomes `http://localhost:8000/blog/` so that the active class can be applied to subpages in the directory?

Answer (score 1):

You can use `slice` filter

```
{% if request.path|slice:":5" == item.link %} active{% endif %}
```

**OR**

You can use `in` operator.

So instead `{% if request.get_full_path == item.link %}` do `{% if item.link in request.get_full_path %}` or to catch homepage `{% if request.get_full_path in item.link and request.get_full_path != '/' or  request.get_full_path == item.link %}`

Comment: This works great if I don't have an item linking to the homepage with ```href="/"```, otherwise, the homepage link is active along with the page which is actually active.

Comment: @SidS, try this one `{% if request.get_full_path in item.link and request.get_full_path != '/' or  request.get_full_path == item.link %}`

Comment: @SidS, You can also use `slice` filter. I have updated my answer.

Comment: Thanks for the answer, but unfortunately your code's outcome isn't what I'm after. It either correctly activates the link that the user's on and incorrectly activates the homepage link, or, activates fine until I visit a child page ```blog/child-page``` for example, here the blog link isn't activated but is activated when I visit ```blog/```. I think there's no easy way of doing this with the built-in template tags, I may have to look into making my own custom ones.

Answer (score 0):

This probably isn't the most efficient way, but at the moment for me, it's the only way.

I created a custom template tag which takes in the context and the menu item object, then returns the `active` class name if the current URL matches the URL of the nav-item (item)

In the HTML, as each nav-item is iterated, the item is passed to the get_active method (a custom template tag that I made)

```
{% load menu_tags %}
{% get_menu "MAIN" as navigation %}
{% for item in navigation.menu_items.all %}
    {% get_active item as active_class %}
    <a class="nav-link {{ active_class }}" href="{{ item.link }}" {% if item.open_in_new_tab %} target="_blank"{% endif %}>{{ item.title }}</a>
{% endfor %}
```

Template tag:

```
@register.simple_tag(takes_context=True)
def get_active(context, item):
    request = context['request']
    currentURL = request.path
    linkURL = item.link
    currentURLStripped = str(currentURL).replace("/", "")
    linkURLStripped = str(linkURL).replace("/", "")
    if linkURLStripped=="" and currentURLStripped=="":
        return "active"
    elif linkURLStripped in currentURLStripped and linkURLStripped!="":
        return "active"
    else:
        return ""
```

The code above simply takes the URL of the page the user is currently on, for example, if the user is on `http://localhost:8000/blog` then `currentURL` will be `/blog/`. The `linkURL` is the URL property of the `item` object, for the item object which links to the contact me page, its URL property will be `/contact-me/` and thus the `linkURL` will be the same.

The method simply strips the "/" from the URL strings. If the URL is for the homepage (i.e. it's `/`) then the variable will be empty. `if linkURLStripped=="" and currentURLStripped=="":` catches the homepage.

`elif linkURLStripped in currentURLStripped and linkURLStripped!="":` catches the other pages and ignores the homepage.